# Is there an Event listener for Doctrine 2 Create Schema?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'd like to insert some records into the database (some default data used for foreign key constraints) on the Doctrine Create Schema Event.

This function is called through the command line (in Symfony2) by firing:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

When this command is run, Doctrine2 generates the schema for the database.

Is there any way to react to this even and insert data into the database?

thanks!

Comment: No, but you can create your own Command: complete your schema update and add your records in one shot.

Comment: Look at [DoctrineFixtureBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) ! It will help you to load initial data.

Comment: @GreenLeaf, can you add that as an answer? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [DoctrineFixtureBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) !

It will help you to load initial data.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new [Console Command](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/console/console_command.html) will accomplish what your looking for.

**Command Code**

MyCool/Bundle/Command/GenerateSchemaUpdateCommand.php

```
<?php
namespace MyCool\Bundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class GenerateSchemaUpdateCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    /**
     * Configure command, set parameters definition and help.
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('mycoolbundle:schema:update')
            ->setDescription('Perform my custom schema update.')
            ->setHelp(sprintf(
            'Performs the doctrine:schema:update plus adds our custom records. \n' .
                PHP_EOL
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Execution Code
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface $input
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output = system('php -f app/console doctrine:schema:update --force');
        // do your custom things here.
        echo $output;
    }
}
```

**Execute your Command**

```
php -f app/console mycoolbundle:schema:update
```

**Adding Arguments**

You can add arguments to your command with the following method:

```
addArgument('var_name', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Help message...')
// InputArgument::REQUIRED is also available here
```

**Notes**

Doing it this way allows you to add alot of functionality to your console commands, plus you'll have direct access to your Models and Entities should you choose to need them.